# iOS - Deleting Rows From UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Before getting into the problem, I must state that I've checked other questions regarding this problem.

I'm having problems deleting rows from UITableView.

My app enables the user to select some contacts and shows their names and numbers in UITableview and saves these info in two mutable arrays called *people* and *numbers*.

This is the method I use for deleting cells.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

//[tableView beginUpdates];
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
   //[numbers removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   //[people removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [self.tableData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

}
//[tableView endUpdates];
[tableView reloadData];}
```

This is my data setting

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import AddressBook;
@import AddressBookUI;

@interface addedContacts : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
NSMutableArray* people;
NSMutableArray* numbers;
IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mTV;
- (IBAction)addPerson:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)editButton:(id)sender;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tableData;

@end
```

I define *tableview* IBOutlet's properties in the beginning of the .m file.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
tableview.delegate = self;
tableview.dataSource = self;}
```

And this is the exception thingy I get;

```
2015-07-14 16:16:06.207 MyTestApp[716:607] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:1368
2015-07-14 16:16:06.491 MyTestApp[716:607] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.
  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (6) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (6),
 plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

So, where did I do wrong?

I can provide first thrown call stack or more code if required.

**More Info**

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView*) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"numbers"]];
return [numbers count];
}


-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return YES;
}
```

Comment: What do you return for `numberOfRowsInSection` also where do you define `self.tableData`

Comment: Have you implemented 
- tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:?

Comment: @random since I defined tableData at the .h file which I provided above, I did not defined it anywhere else. And Philip; yes, I'm adding the code in more info section for you to see.

Comment: @TheSaurus ah, sorry, didn't see that in the `.h`

Comment: If you are loading the array from NSUserDefaults when getting the count you need to save it to NSUserDefaults every time you remove something from the array. Otherwise the array is the same as before you deleted an object from it.

Comment: Why have you removed the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `reloadData` straight after calling `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths`. This might cause animation conflicts that may be the cause of your current crash.

Comment: I must admit, I was thinking about that. This solved the problem, thank you.
Also much thanks to Philip and random, I've arranged the code to update correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You should be returning `self.tableData.count` for your `numberOfRowsInSection` method. As of now you're not deleting from the data source that's being returned from `numberOfRowsInSection` so your count is off.

You also shouldn't be accessing `NSUserDefaults` there. In your `viewDidLoad` you should load everything from `NSUserDefaults`, allow the user to make changes and updatee to the data. Then when you go to leave the view, save everything back down to `NSUserDefaults`.